# Rigorous formulation of Wick theorem at finite temperature

Tags: quantum-field-theory, temperature, second-quantization, wick-theorem

Consider a quadratic Hamiltonian in second quantization. For simplicity, let $H = \sum_{n =0}^\infty \epsilon_n c_n^* c_n$ where $\epsilon_n$ may satisfy some conditions. Let the average be
$$
\langle \cdots \rangle = \frac{1}{Z} \text{tr}(\cdots e^{-\beta H})
$$
Then is there a mathematically rigorous proof for Wick's theorem at finite temperatures? I remember a paper (by Gaudin) proving the subject, but it was in a different language and I couldn't find a translation. Are there any other good references?

Comment: I guess the paper is by Gaudin?

Comment: If you are familiar with path integrals, all of the necessary ingredients can be found in Zinn-Justin's book *Path Integrals in Quantum Mechanics*. In the first chapter he first shows that Wick's theorem is a property of the Gaussian integrals which appear in correlation functions, and in the second chapter he shows that the finite-temperature correlation functions of a quadratic Hamiltonians are of the assumed form for Wick's theorem to apply.

Comment: @SethWhitsitt I have seen the path integral formulation of Wick's theorem. However, I'm a little troubled by the fact that the path integral isn't well-defined in the infinite-dimensional case, so I was wondering if there was a way to prove Wick's theorem using only properties of the trace function and second quantization

Comment: Check out pages 170-172 in the following pdf: http://www.phys.lsu.edu/~jarrell/COURSES/ADV_SOLID_HTML/Other_online_texts/Many-body%20quantum%20theory%20in%0Acondensed%20matter%20physics%0AHenrik%20Bruus%20and%20Karsten%20Flensberg.pdf